# How to restart timer at the onPress in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

I have made a small functionality for timer, where a timer will countdown from `10`. When it reaches `0`, the timer will hide, and a restart button will come at that place. Till this far, I am able to do it.

But I wanted to restart the timer when `Restart` appears after countdown is completed.

Below is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timer: 10,
      displayButton: 'none',
      displayTime: 'flex'
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
      this.decrementClock();
    }, 1000);
  }
  decrementClock = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({timer: prevState.timer - 1}),
      () => {
        if (this.state.timer === 0) {
          this.setState({
            displayTime: "none",
            displayButton: "flex"
          })
        }
      },
    );
  };
  restartButton() {
    this.setState({
      displayTime: "flex",
      displayButton: "none",
      timer: 30,
    })
  }
<Text style={{display: this.state.displayTime}}>{this.state.timer}</Text>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.restartButton}>
    <Text style={{display:this.state.displayButton}}>Restart</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

As you can see, `Restart` appears when countdown is finished, But when I click on `Restart` it is showing me error: `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your method
When you invoke the `restartButton()` function, it returns the value of `this` within the context which in this case is the `null`.

Since the `this` context of App is the one that `restartButton()` should be using, we have to use the `.bind()` method on it in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timer: 10,
      displayButton: 'none',
      displayTime: 'flex'
    };
this.restartButton= this.restartButton.bind(this);
  }
```

and the other approach(arrow-function) is if you don't want to bind the function

```
restartButton =()=> {
    this.setState({
      displayTime: "flex",
      displayButton: "none",
      timer: 30,
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class component, we cannot directly call the methods that use this keyword as an in-class component this keyword refers to the object it called from as here it called from touchable opacity in might refers as the touchable object because of that you are receiving the error for this.setState is not a function as there is no function such as setState in touchable. so you have to bind the methods with a component to update the state or you can simply call the function as below code

onPress={() => this.restartButton()}

To bind the function you can use the below code in your class constructor

this.restartButton= this.restartButton.bind(this);